# Java for loop is probably broken or my code is wrong

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Map;

 // Compiler version JDK 11.0.2

 class Main
 {
   public static void main(String args[])
   { 
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
     long N = scan.nextLong();
     
     long log = N;
     long digit = 0L;
     
     while(log>=1L)
     {
       log = log/10L;
       digit = digit+1L;
     }
     
     int i = 0;
     long cmonPlease = (long) Math.pow(10,i+1);
     int you = (int) Math.ceil(digit/3)+1;
     int totally = (int) Math.floor(i/3);
     long ruined = N%cmonPlease;
     long my = (long) Math.pow(10,i);
     long code = (long) Math.floor(ruined/my);
     
     long[][] format = new long[you+1][3];
     for(i=0; i<digit; i++)
     {
       cmonPlease = (long) Math.pow(10,i+1);
       totally = (int) Math.floor(i/3); 
       ruined = N%cmonPlease;
       my = (long) Math.pow(10,i);
       code = (long) Math.floor(ruined/my); 
       format[totally][i%3]=code;
     }
     
     
     
     /*for(i=0; i<format.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<format[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println("Values at arr["+i+"]["+j+"] is "+format[i][j]);
        }
    }*/
     
     
     HashMap<Long,String> ones = new HashMap<Long,String>();
     ones.put(0L,"zero");
     ones.put(1L,"one");
     ones.put(2L,"two");
     ones.put(3L,"three");
     ones.put(4L,"four");
     ones.put(5L,"five");
     ones.put(6L,"six");
     ones.put(7L,"seven");
     ones.put(8L,"eight");
     ones.put(9L,"nine");
     
     HashMap<Long,String> teens = new HashMap<Long,String>();
     teens.put(0L,"ten");
     teens.put(1L,"eleven");
     teens.put(2L,"twelve");
     teens.put(3L,"thirteen");
     teens.put(4L,"fourteen");
     teens.put(5L,"fifteen");
     teens.put(6L,"sixteen");
     teens.put(7L,"seventeen");
     teens.put(8L,"eightteen");
     teens.put(9L,"nineteen");
     
     HashMap<Long,String> tens = new HashMap<Long,String>();
     tens.put(2L,"twenty");
     tens.put(3L,"thirty");
     tens.put(4L,"fourty");
     tens.put(5L,"fifty");
     tens.put(6L,"sixty");
     tens.put(7L,"seventy");
     tens.put(8L,"eighty");
     tens.put(9L,"ninety");
     
     HashMap<Long,String> illions = new HashMap<Long,String>();
     illions.put(format[0][0],"");
     if(digit>3L)
     {
       illions.put(format[1][0],"thousand");
     }
     if(digit>6L)
     {
       illions.put(format[2][0],"million");
     }
     if(digit>9L)
     {
       illions.put(format[3][0],"billion");
     }
     
     Map<Long, Map<Long, String>> position = new HashMap<>();
     for(i=0;i<you;i++)
     {
       if(format[i][1]>1L)
       {
         position.put(format[i][1],tens);
         position.put(format[i][0],ones);
       }
       else if(format[i][1]==1L)
       {
         position.put(format[i][1],teens);
       }
       else if(format[i][1]==0L)
       {
         position.put(format[i][0],ones);
       }
       position.put(format[i][2],ones);
     }
     
     String out = "";
     for(i=you-1;i>=0;i--)
     {
       if(format[i][0]==0&format[i][1]==0&format[i][2]==0)
       {
         i=i-1;
       }
       
       if(format[i][2]!=0L)
       {
         out = out + position.get(format[i][2]).get(format[i][2]);
         out = out + " hundred ";
       }
       
       if(format[i][1]==1L)
       {
         out = out + position.get(format[i][1]).get(format[i][0]);
       }
       else if(format[i][1]>1L)
       {
         out = out + position.get(format[i][1]).get(format[i][1])+" "+position.get(format[i][0]).get(format[i][0]);
       }
       
       if(format[i][1]==0L&format[i][0]!=0L)
       {
         out= out + position.get(format[i][0]).get(format[i][0]);
       }
       
       out = out + " "+illions.get(format[i][0]);
       
       if(i!=0L)
       {
         out = out + " ";
       }
     }
     System.out.println(out);
   }
 }
```

Can somebody check what's wrong with my code? I just can't get my head over it.

I was solving a Dcoder challenge and had to go through a whole bunch of mental gymnastics to get to the point I'm at now. It mostly works, say if you put non repeated digits like 987654

> 987654 nine hundred eighty seven thousand six hundred fifty four
>
> Process finished.

But in case of repeated digits two things happen:

1. It repeats the illions' elements multiple times even though **i** is supposed to decrease.
2. The tens' elements won't get added to **out** but ones' does

> 88888
> eight eight thousand eight hundred eight eight thousand
>
> Process finished.

The program is to take any integer N such that, 0≤N≤10¹⁰ and convert it in numerals.

I personally think the problem is somewhere in how java deals with division or something but I can be wrong.

This is my first StackOverflow question and also being a novice developer (as you can see from my code) please excuse any mistakes.

Comment: Can you replace your "angry" variable names with sensible names? It will make it easier for us to understand what you are trying to do and where the problem might be?

Comment: what loop do you think is "broken" and why do you think it is? did you try debugging your code, or add print statements (at least) to verify the values of key variables during a run?

Comment: Your `format` array seems to contain the individual digits you've found in the number, right? If so you're potentially overwriting entries in your maps if digits repeat, e.g. `position.put(format[i][1],tens);` and `position.put(format[i][0],ones);` would result in only `ones` being in the map if `format[i][1]` and `format[i][0]` have the same value.

Comment: "I personally think the problem is somewhere in how java deals with division" - the chances of you finding a bug in Java are monumentally low. You should start with the *assumption* that the bug is in your code. It's a much more productive attitude. You should then try to reduce this to a *minimal* example, having stepped through the code carefully in a debugger.

Comment: @Thomas Yeah thanks. But how do I solve this? Do I just switch keys with values? Will that work?

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for trying to sound like a narcissist. But I've seen people complaining how floating point numbers or something like that sometimes cause errors so I kinda assumed...

Comment: @Sdrago: *Misunderstanding* how floating point work can indeed cause errors. But an attitude *starting* with "Java for loop is probably broken" and "I personally think the problem is somewhere in how java deals with division" is not the solution to that. Instead, it's "I guess Java doesn't work the way I expected it to - **I should change my expectations**."

Comment: @JonSkeet Dang I just wanted an answer.

The StackOverflow community isn't very welcoming I see...

Comment: @Sdrago you ask questions that aren't related to your problem, yet are expecting us to spend our spare time to solve your issues, what exactly do you expect? You give limited and incorrect information. The SO community is quite welcoming, and Jon is one of the best (and most willing) at helping out, if you spend enough time on SO, you'll notice that. You start with false assumptions, write code in a way that makes little sense, and you honestly think the problem is with those trying to understand and help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a map for position which will be overridden for repeated values:
Consider 88:

```
position.put(format[i][1], tens);
position.put(format[i][0], ones);
```

The first line sets `position[8] = tens` then the second line overwrites it with `position[8] = ones`, so you are losing the `tens`.

`format` probably could just be a list of integers where the first value is the least significant digit, e.g. for 123 the list would be `[3, 2, 1]`.
Then you wouldn't need all the complicated maps within maps, etc.

Comment: Yeah but, it's a 2d array and the second indices are different.

So.... That shouldn't be a problem right? And it seems to be working just fine in case of different digits. Why doesn't it get overiden then?


And yeah... I'm new to java so  things like lists still seem too fancy to me. In case if you couldn't tell... I've barely scraped it together with whatever functions/packages I could find.

Comment: Ok ok! So basically you are saying that hashmap can't containt multiple elemnets as in a mathematical set?

That makes sense... Let me try

Comment: Lists are far less fancy than hashmaps ;)